# Method that deactivates a UI Panel some how is affecting the scale of my selected Panel?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I have a Canvas object and it has a bunch of Panels that are children of it. Basically every time I want to open a new panel I perform a check and see if there is one already open and if so I want to close it, otherwise just go to the next child object. For some reason now, it just hangs my project up. No errors are thrown and nothing happens. I already have everything set into my public variables and I have been able to comment out this method call and then the rest of the code works fine, however, none of my panels close because that method is the one that did that for me. Is there something wrong here that I am not seeing. This method did work previously and I have not touched it since. Each panel has its animator and that is how I differentiate them from all the other RectTransforms under my Canvas object.

```
public void CheckIfActiveBeforeClosing(GameObject obj)
{
    RectTransform[] children = obj.GetComponentsInChildren<RectTransform>();
    foreach (RectTransform child in children)
    {
        if (!child.gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>() != null)
            {
                taskAnimController.ClosePanel(child.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After it exits from this method I call an OpenPanel function. For some reason when the above method is included the scale of the panel I open is changed to 0,0,0. Once I selected another panel to open the scale changes back to normal and the new selected panel changes its scale and so on. However, no where in my code do I mess with the scale of the object. The OpenPanel call also does not activate my Panel either. All it says it to set the object active and changes a animation bool parameter.

Comment: Is the animation animating the scale?

Comment: Yes, however, I use the same animations for all of my UI Panels and the same Open/Close methods this only effects a section of my UI where I am checking if it is open or not and closing if there is one open already. If that makes since. But, there is another section of my UI that uses this method also and it has no problems closing and opening another panel.

Comment: The thing that is different about this one that I am having problems with is that I am checking the tag and layer and see if it is part of a certain group and then show the panel that is unique to that object that I raycasted if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the mistake after doing a lot of debugging. For some reason I had two listeners for my OnClick method and once I removed one of them it fixed the problem. For some reason I had a listener as a component and had another one in my script that called this method. Must have been up too late coding haha.